# what is the dojo AMD loading sequence?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I've tried looking for the order in which the dojo AMD loads it's modules, as I have seen in other questions that the order the modules are placed in the require[] block matter.

```
require(["dojo/dom",
"dijit/Dialog",
"dijit/form/Form", 
"dijit/form/TextBox",
"dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
"dijit/form/Textarea",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dojox/validate/web",
"dojo/request",
"dojo/domReady!"],
```

would be an example of the require block...

Comment: *How* do you think does the order matter?

Comment: They are loaded in parallel using ajax in the specified order, making as many requests, as the browser can handle

Comment: I realize they are loaded in the specified order, and that it's done as fast as can be done and done asynchronously.  And I think that the "dojo/dom" module needs loaded first, and that the "dojo/domReady!" is probably the last one but, are there conventions for which modules and the order to which they _should_ be specificed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... there is no real loading sequence (that's the Asynchronous in AMD). The `dojo/domReady!` module isn't loaded last either, its the module itself that delays the AMD callback being executed.

The only reason why someone would put the `dojo/domReady!` last, is because the returned object has no use. However, use or no use, if you need a specific module that you put after it, then you still have to add an extra parameter, for example:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/aspect"], function(dom, garbage, aspect) {

});
```

The code above works and will stay working even if you scramble the order of the modules, the only problem here is that, because we want the `aspect` module, we need to add a second parameter for the domReady module.

So, the common practice is to put all modules which you don't need (the returned object at least) at the end of the sequence, for example:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/aspect", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, aspect, garbage) {

});
```

And because parameters in JavaScript are optional, we can leave the ones we don't need away (if they're at the end), so the code above is the same as:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/aspect", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, aspect) {

});
```

And that's why it's often added as last parameter. Though there are other modules as well that are commonly placed at the end, for example:

- All `dojo/NodeList-*` modules: These modules add extra functionality to the `NodeList` module. However, they are applied directly and the returned object of these modules is not useful.
- `dojo/parser`: When you configure Dojo to automatically parse all HTML (using `parseOnLoad`), then you don't necessarily need a reference to the parser module. However, you have to add it to make it work.
- All widgets: If you're using declarative markup, you don't need an instance to the module itself, however, you have to load it to make it work.

Comment: Why is it then that a lot of answers to some other dojo questions about why function signatures aren't working - that people have suggested the order matters?  Thats what was confusing me...because Asynchronous means that there doesn't have to be an order - or at least that they wont finish loading in a particular order.  So, maybe I should ask "In what order does dojo start loading it's AMD?' Is it based on the order of the require block? Or is it based on predefined hierarchy of modules?"

Comment: Well, most of these questions are about the mapping order. It doesn't matter how you order your modules, but what does matter is that the parameters in the callback should be in the same order as how you defined them in the array of modules. So: `require([ "1", "2", "3"], function(1, 2, 3) { });`

Comment: But how you order the array of modules doesn't matter, the following is exactly the same as the other code: `require([ "2", "1", "3" ], function(2, 1, 3) { });`

Comment: And how they load is a bit more complex, they start being loaded by their index (so in the same order you defined them), but it's a recursive function that also loads its dependencies, so it's quite hard to determine the actual order. And even if you knew it, you shouldn't rely on it as it shouldn't matter in which order they start loading.

Comment: So that is touching more on the answer im looking for...  I'm aware that the require([]) modules need to be in the same order in the function() in order to use them.  I guess I'll just have to go into the debugger and step through and try out a few different require([]) sigs.

Comment: And may I ask why exactly you want to know that? It's not that it can be useful and it might change in the future as well. Right now the AMD loader has a lot of legacy code support that may be removed in Dojo 2.0.

Comment: I just want to get a better picture of whats going on under the hood so to speak